# How to create and save .docx document on C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, ms-word, ms-office

I need to manipulate .docx documents using C/Visual C++. Any samples i found is c# samples.
 How to do so?

Comment: [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776) from brief googeling.

Comment: Use .docx xml format for the saving file in docx, have a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Are you sure you need to? The format is very opaque, the complete specification is 6000+ pages long, and the only alternative is .NET stuff which uses a whole lot of com boilerplate under the scenes that you will have a bad time trying to translate into C++. Are you sure you can't use plain text for whatever you are doing ?

Comment: If you need markup, use HTML or RTF. Almost anything that reads .docx can also read HTML and RTF.

Answer (score 3):

What I've found is that Microsoft wants you to either use .NET or use their Office Automation API to invoke Word to perform the manipulations for you. Depending on how low you want to go with these manipulations, you might be able to get by with the Office Automation API. If not, you may have to get your hands dirty with the Open Office XML format that's behind the .docx file format.

[Here's Microsoft's skimpy documentation on Office Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776)

[And here's an article that goes into it a bit more, although it may be out of date.](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/tutorials/article.php/c14519/Microsoft-Word-Automation-Class.htm)

I just thought that one big issue with Office Automation is that you need to have Word to do anything with it. Of course, this all depends on what exactly you need to to.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://libopc.codeplex.com/